# Вывод рекурсивной итерации в новый массив

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, foreach

не могу сделать вывод рекурсии в новый массив. Вот так работает, выводит текстовые строки:

```
function recurse($item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recurse($value);
        } else {
            echo "$key : $value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Но я хочу записать пары $key => $value в новый массив с выводом последнего как $dataArray из функции таким образом, но это не работает

```
function recurse($item) {
    $dataArray = [];
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            recurse($value);
        } else {
            $dataArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $dataArray;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, Вы возвращаете массив в никуда. Во-вторых, полученный из recurse() массив нужно объединить с имеющимся.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что с массивом все сложно. Проще выводить в строку, а потом это разбирать в массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, мой комментарий не приблизил к решению, поэтому демонстрирую наглядно:

```
function recurse($item)
{
    $dataArray = [];
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $dataArray = array_merge($dataArray, recurse($value));
        } else {
            $dataArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $dataArray;
}
```

Есть решение в одну строчку:

```
$out = []; // массив с данными
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($v, $k) use (&$out){$out[$k] = $v;});
```

Но учтите, что элементы с одинаковыми ключами будут перезаписываться.

Comment: Да это работает и я так тоже пробовал, но как вы правильно заметили, данные перезаписываются. За array_walk_recursive отдельное спасибо, знаю что такой механизм есть, но детально не смотрел. А есть вариант избежать перезаписи данных? Пока в голову приходит использовать как то array_key_last, но возможно есть другие варианты

Comment: Массив не может содержать два элемента с одинаковым ключом. Выход из положения: заполнять индексный массив элементами вида [‘key’ => …, ‘value’ => …]